# Using conditional statements during the Wordpress loop

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress

I'm using the [Vitrux theme](http://themeforest.net/item/vitrux-responsive-fullscreen-portfolio-wp-theme/2992618) in Wordpress. The home page display posts in a tiled layout from the 'Portfolio' post type. I want to get three posts from a different post type ('Shoots'). Adding the code here after the call to the loop works:

```
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if ($post->post_title == "Latest Shoots")
            {
            $portfolio_replacement = 'shoots'; // the post type to query
            query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'post_type'=>$portfolio_replacement, 'posts_per_page' => 3));
            }
```

but only if the 'Latest Shoots' post is the first one in the main portfolio. You can see this in action here:

http://www.snaprockandpop.samcampsall.co.uk

(the posts added by the if statement are the three nearest the bottom of the layout, which replace the 'Latest Shoots' post).

How would I create conditional statements like this that will execute at any point in the Wordpress loop? I can't guarantee that this one will always happen be at the beginning, plus I'd like to write some other queries to change the layout on this site.

What's the best way to do this, and how would I go about learning it? I've got a very basic understanding of PHP but I'm keen to learn more, so please be gentle!

Comment: Did you get something like this working? I'm looking to test the title name. Then fire off my true statement once a match is made.

Comment: Afraid not, although it must be possible! I was building on a remote server, so couldn't effectively debug my issue - if you want to make it work I'd recommend using Xamp or something to have a local build that you can debug properly. In the end I just created multiple loops and then reset them when they were done i.e. loop query -> reset, loop query -> reset, loop query -> reset. Not pretty, but it worked: http://www.snaprockandpop.co.uk